# Is it possible to connect to DB in Oracle APEX application externally?

Tags: java, oracle, external, dblink, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to query the table stored in Oracle APEX application externally (using Java). But, i am quite not sure on achieving it. Because, inside APEX i was able to access external databases using dblink. But, the other way around is puzzling me. It starts from what should be the connect string, will there be host & port details etc.,.

Search on oracle docs and other dba forums didn't cover this scenario. It would be a great help if someone can give a pointer on this.

Comment: I don't get the question. You have an Apex application, you have a Java application, you have a database. Your Apex application accesses the database, now you need to make the Java application access the database. Or do you want the Apex application to act as some sort of webservice?

Comment: @Gimby The database is part of Apex Application and i want to access that database using Java.

Comment: Yes but I am trying to understand why you think Apex is involved in that process. You have an Oracle database that just happens to also expose some Apex functionality, but it seems your real question is how to connect to that Oracle database from a Java application. Something which has been asked and answered countless times already.

Comment: @Gimby This is not the APEX application which is available after installing Oracle DB. This is [Oracle APEX](http://apex.oracle.com) portal where we can create database applications. I am trying to access the DB which is provisioned as part of Oracle APEX online application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments you're trying to access the apex.oracle.com Database externally - which isn't possible.
The only valid way to access your database in the online demo workspaces from oracle is via the SQL Workshop or your APEX applications.
If there's a need for accessing the data from outside i highly suggest using the RESTfull services from APEX. A direct connection via JDBC isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. Based on your pointer, the [RESTful](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/RESTful_WS_oll/RESTful_WS_oll.html) looks like a definite fix. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you with RESTful services, i am able to query DB inside APEX Application. Thanks again for the pointer.