# Cannot create new connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a new connection. I recently installed Oracle SQL Developer but I am getting this error and it's freaking me out. Can anybody help me to resolve this ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

Comment: Use the Service name (instead of: SID).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318856/php-oci-connect-not-found/49342642#49342642). Are you sure that you have the SSID named orcl? You can check it via Database configuration Assistant. Choose Configure an existing database, or create a new database and use that ssid. Also sometimes this happens because of your firewall, so disable it and try again. Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318856/php-oci-connect-not-found/49342642#49342642) for further queries.